# How can I retrive just the unmatched result using LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, db2, left-join

Assuming that I have two tables, with a single column each:

```
A    B
-    -
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    6
```

Using LEFT JOIN I receive the follow result:

```
select * from a LEFT OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;


a |  b
--+-----
1 | null
2 | null
3 |    3
4 |    4
```

What can I do to receive just the unmatched results from A, as bellow?

```
a |  b
--+-----
1 | null
2 | null
```

Obs: I can't use the clause `where b.b=null`. It seems it doesn't work in mainframe DB2.
Tks

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE b IS NULL`.

Comment: It worked. Tks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use where condition

```
   Select a.a,b.b  from a left join b on a.a=b.b where b.b is null
```

Comment: As I said, in the question, I can't use the clause where b.b=null. It seems it doesn't work in mainframe DB2. Tks

Comment: @FabricioFontes why b.b is null will not work in db2?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close: You only need to add a selector:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.a = b.b
WHERE
  b.b IS NULL
;
```

Comment: As I said, in the question, I can't use the clause where b.b=null. It seems it doesn't work in mainframe DB2. Tks

Comment: @FabricioFontes b.b`=`null might not work - the correct ANSI SQL is b.b `IS NULL`

Comment: Please accept the answer or edit your OQ so that this inorfmation is easily findable for future references

Comment: How can I accept the answer? I don't know where I can do that. Tks